# Oracle Query Performance Improvement

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing

I have two tables with the below structure

**INPUTFILELOG** with columns as

```
FILE_ID
RECORD_SEQ
ACCOUNT
CHILD_ACCOUNT
```

**PURGE** with column as

```
ACCOUNT
DATE
DETAILS
```

**QUERY**

```
delete from INPUTFILELOG il
where  exists
       ( select 1 from PURGE po
         where  po.account = ':NUMBER'
         and    ( po.account = il.account OR po.account = il.child_account ) )
```

The performance of the above query is bad even though there are indexes on **PURGE.ACCOUNT** and **INPUTFILELOG.ACCOUNT** and **INPUTFILELOG.CHILD_ACCOUNT**. Can someone
 please help ?

**UPDATE**

I tried the below query. Does it look good? Is there a better way to handle it?

```
delete from INPUTLOG sif
where  exists
       ( select t.fileno, t.rec
         from   ( SELECT sif2.FILE_ID as fileno, sif2.RECORD_SEQ as rec
                  FROM   purge po 
                         INNER JOIN INPUTLOG sif2 
                              ON (   po.ACCOUNT = sif2.ACCOUNT
                                  OR po.ACCOUNT = sif2.CHILD_ACCOUNT )
                  where  po.account = ':NUMBER' ) t
         WHERE  sif.FILE_ID = t.FILEno
         AND    sif.record_seq = t.rec)
```

Comment: please format code as code. see your other posts how to do this.

Comment: Hi Ram, A few pointers: 1) If you convert the delete to a select and check, does that also take time - in that case that is a good indication that query is surely bad else there is a chance that it is the delete operation that is taking time and not the fault of the query. 2) how much data does actually get deleted  by this poorly doing query, is that huge? 3) post the execution plan of the query and verify if that has oppertunities for improvement.

Comment: Hi, I missed mentioning some points 1) The query performance improves when only one of the condition (in OR) is included. If both are included a full table scan of INPUTFILELOG takes place. 2)  For each account passed as the host variable about 100 records get deleted. 3 ) The same query works fine on DB2.

Comment: Is `account` unique for the `purge` table or can there be duplicates?

Comment: Yes account is unique in purge table

Comment: Do you happen to have any foreign keys on these tables which refer to other tables, or are there foreign keys on other tables which refer to these tables?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your latest inputs, I would like to suggest to break the orignial query into the following two queries and validate if they are functinally fine (which I think they should be) and validate their performance. I think the following two may perform better and the issue here could be due to the "OR OPERATOR" that leads to the full table scan.

```
DELETE FROM INPUTLOG il
      WHERE EXISTS
               (SELECT 1
                  FROM PURGE po
                 WHERE po.account = ':NUMBER' AND (po.account = il.account))


DELETE FROM INPUTLOG il
      WHERE EXISTS
               (SELECT 1
                  FROM PURGE po
                 WHERE     po.account = ':NUMBER'
                       AND (po.account = il.child_account))
```

Comment: Agree your suggestion works. Can it be done using single query?. I tried once approach and updated the question. Could you please provide your opinion

Comment: Hi Ram, I not sure if it works and you are the best person to find out as you have the system where you can verify the execution plan and timing details. I am a bit skeptical as I see the OR clause which I guess can lead to issues but I am not 100% sure here. I would ask you to carefully verify and decide. If you find the execution plan and timings are not good then you can go to the approach of using the two queries that avoid the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I meant, verify details like whether the full table scan or a very large index range scan still happens with your revised query.

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete one account only. If there were only, say, ten accounts in the table, a full table scan would be the best way to delete that big percentage of table data. But you say that deletion is much faster when you only either delete accounts or child accounts. I gather that the added up time of the two deletes is very much shorter then the one with your combined query. So obviously an index is used then, which means it must be only a very small percentage of the table that gets deleted.

Two ideas:

1. Well, obviously you can just run two delete statements instead of one and have achieved what you want to.
2. Show the DBMS very clearly that it's only one account you want to delete from the table `INPUTFILELOG` (by `inputfilelog.account = ...`).

Hence:

```
delete from inputfilelog where account =
  (select account from purge where account = ':NUMBER');

delete from inputfilelog where child_account = 
  (select account from purge where account = ':NUMBER');
```

Maybe the `=` suffices even to make the combined statemet run fast (but using two indexes combined with `OR` usually isn't).

```
delete from inputfilelog
where account = (select account from purge where account = ':NUMBER')
or child_account = (select account from purge where account = ':NUMBER');
```

Another approach with `inputfilelog.account = ...`:

```
delete from inputfilelog
where (account = :NUMBER or child_account = :NUMBER)
and exists (select * from purge where account = :NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have indexes , if you use "OR" operator in the Where clause, index will not be used.
If you want to benefit Indexes avoid "OR" operator in where clause.

Thanks & Regards